# PHP MVC Как получить данные из модели?

Tags: php, mvc, twig

Пытаюсь разобраться с данным php фреймворком: https://github.com/daveh/php-mvc
Там используется Twig. Первый раз с ним сталкиваюсь.

В модели User есть метод getAll (выборка всех пользователей).

В контроллере главной страницы (Home) есть метод indexAction, который возвращает вид (представление) `View::renderTemplate('Home/index.html');`

**Самый главный вопрос:** Так как мне теперь вывести список всех пользователей в представлении?

Я не могу писать php код в index.html (нельзя изменять на .php, выдаёт ошибку).

Выяснил, что можно передавать переменные при создании представления:

```
View::render('Home/index.php', [
    'name'    => 'Dave'
]);
```

Но и это не сильно помогло. Вместо Dave мне нужен **метод** из модели, который возвратит мне список всех пользователей.

Буду чрезвычайно благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

О, боже! Я разобрался!)

Нужно было:

1. В контроллер главной страницы Home добавить `use \App\Models\User;`,
   чтобы обращаться к модели User и её методам.
2. В **этом же** контроллере в методе формирования представления (View)
   добавить параметр (массив со списком юзеров, который и
   будет передаваться во View):

   `View::renderTemplate('Home/index.html',
                       [ 'users' => User::getAll() ]);`
3. Теперь у нас есть массив users, который можно вывести во View с помощью такой конструкции:

   ```
   {% for user in users %}
      <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Если я что-то неправильно написал, поправьте меня, пожалуйста) Это мой первый день в изучении Twig и практики с фреймворком php MVC)